# Why is the prompt for updating the host key not working in git-bash (Windows) / PuTTY?

Tags: git, git-bash, putty

GitHub recently changed their host key:
https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/

I use PuTTY for SSH keys ans git-bash for Windows.

When pushing my repository to GitHub, I get the following message:

[image]

But no matter if I enter <kbd>y</kbd>/<kbd>n</kbd>/nothing and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, nothing happens, the cursor just jumps to the next line. How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using PuTTY/Plink for SSH with your Git for Windows. The Plink does not work well within Git when it needs an input.

- Either switch to OpenSSH.
- Or just cache the `github.com` SSH hostkey outside of Git first.

  Either from PuTTY (by trying to connect to `github.com`):

  [image]
- Or using Plink in console (`cmd` or `bash` or whatever):

  ```
  C:\>plink github.com
  ```

  [image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for the fast reply.